# magento attributes / multiple atts with one selection

Tags: magento, attributes, magento-1.7

really could do with your expert advice / knowledge & help...

We have a client who we built a magento site for. He sells parts for motorbikes, jet-skis, motocross etc..

We set up three attributes "Manufacturer" then "Model" then "Year" - and this was the selection process inside each product to drill down a price (as price changes on the models year) to achieve the pricing structure he wanted we used a simpler config products plugin that worked a charm. (which I found searching through these forums)

Problem.. The "Model" attribute is getting way too big (crashing the browser and timing out - and approaching what I have been told is the limit for attributes) so we have to rethink the logic (as last resort is to change the whole site and add them all as simple products and use filters instead - which the client does not want)

After days fo stress and researching we are still none the wiser...

one idea would be to split the model attribute into manufacturer.. so "Hond_Model" .. "Aprilla_Model" and so on.. but then we cant keep the structure of one product with all the options inside, be great of we could have inside the product (front end)

- select honda model
- select aprilla model
- select Can Am Model
- Year

but the user can choose one model from any three of the "model" drop downs, then it blanks out the other 2 model attributes and lets the user select the year to get a price.
But in the back end when I try this all three "Model" attributes have a red asterix and require an input in all three..

HELP!

Sorry if some of this is basic I am a designer who is learning magento with the help of my developer for the past 6 months so still new to this but already way out of my depth.

Any help would be so appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Given the level of complexity, the relative newness of your company with Magento, and particulars of the automotive fitment domain, it might be wise to buy an existing fitment module (e.g. [Year Make Model Extension](http://www.magentocommerce.com/magento-connect/year-make-model-extension.html) - ***not* an endorsement** - i have no firsthand knowledge of this extension) to bootstrap your development or to learn from. You should check with module vendor first to make sure that the code is suitable for this purpose (not obfuscated / encrypted, written using Magento conventions).

There are several approaches which can be taken depending on how frontend presentation and backend reporting should work, but these are too broad to be discussed here.

Comment: Thank you for you reply, all of the above makes perfect sense and understand it may be a vague topic that could have many outcomes. I will take a look at the suggested plugin - Thank you again for your time and help.